# How to find partition function of the system of particles having magnetic moment μ placed in a magnetic field B and particles obey M-B Statistics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Here we get two energy levels uB and -uB which are discrete, but particles follow MB stats, it means there energy is continuous. I am getting confused, what is the role of the MB stats in such a case?